# Using FFT to enhance fingerprints

Tags: python, image-processing, filtering, fft

I'm trying to make a program for filtering fingerprints, but I'm kinda new to this whole image processing stuff and therefore I'm stumbling a bit in the beginning. In this particular part of the program I want to do a fourier fast transform and use the magnitude to give an enhanced version as I've read in some papers. However it is not giving a satisfactory result (Quite a bad one actually)

```
def fftf(pix):

    pix_fft = numpy.fft.fft2(pix)
    tmp_fft = pix_fft * numpy.abs(pix_fft)**0.45
    pix_enh = numpy.fft.ifft2(tmp_fft)

    return pix_enh
```

Wondering if I'm missing something obvious (I've used histogram equalization beforehand to increase contrast)

Comment: To enhance a fingerprint image you need more complex filters
[(see this page)](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/FingerPrints/Docs/index.html). 
The book 'Hand book of fingerprint recognition by Maltony and Jain' may help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This will help me along